# CSS width not centering the image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using wordpress as my CMS, and have used a theme of my choice. The theme shows a slider (carousel) on the home page, but takes up too much space. I tried to edit the width and height to be 80%, but the UI gets screwed. The slider does not center, or the frame with the left right arrows come closer. The image gets smashed. I need to get the css right for this.

I tried the following

1. modified width and height to 80%
2. reduced the px values, messed it up further

Below I have relevant css and html portions of the code.

```
<div id="slides">
  <div class="slides_container slide" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: block;">
    <div class="slides_control" style="position: relative; width: 2736px; height: 480px; left: -912px;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 912px; z-index: 5;">
       <a href=""><img src="http://localhost/taxeeta/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/116.png?1358343444279" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 912px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
       <a href=""><img src="http://localhost/taxeeta/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/215.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slides {
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left: 0px;
 z-index: 100;
 width: 897px;
 margin-left: 14px;
}

.slides_container {
 width: 912px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.slides_control {
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left: 0px;
 z-index: 100;
 width: 897px;
 margin-left: 14px;
}
```

Comment: just asking.. do you realize your html has inline style css?

Comment: even if i did, i wont be able to understand it. html css is not my cup of tea :)

Comment: Apparently not HTML nor CSS is something you'd understand. Because there's no such thing as HTML CSS, because there's HTML and there's CSS. Two cups of tea to put it in your language. ;)

Comment: Sure Robert, I couldn't agree any less with you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that there is jo javascript code modifying the element-css?
Did you changes the width of slides and slides_control as the same?
(sorry iam not able to write comments...)